# Auto Refresh WooCommerce checkout form fields after coupon is added or removed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

My WooCommerce's store offers 100% discount codes on certain occasions. In cases like that, I don't want to collect users' addresses. I need to set up address fields in checkout to be required conditionally, only if total after discounts is more than 0.

I have created a function that will make address fields not required and hidden if the cart total after discounts equals 0.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'customising_checkout_fields', 10000, 1 );
function customising_checkout_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
    
    if ( $total == 0 ) {
        $address_fields['address_1']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['address_2']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['company']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['country']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['city']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['state']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false; 
        
        $address_fields['address_1']['hidden'] = true;
        $address_fields['address_2']['hidden'] = true;
        $address_fields['company']['hidden'] = true;
        $address_fields['country']['hidden'] = true;
        $address_fields['city']['hidden'] = true;
        $address_fields['state']['hidden'] = true;
        $address_fields['postcode']['hidden'] = true; 
    }
    return $address_fields;
}
```

This works fine. The problem is it loads only after users goes from cart to checkout with coupon already applied in cart. If user wants to add the coupon in checkout, fields are not updated automatically (only price is). Same goes opposite direction - if user removes a coupon and price is no longer 0, the fields are still hidden unless user manually refreshes the page.

How to code a function that will automatically update the billing details pane, same as WooCommerce currently updates cart totals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, As this is related to a server side PHP function, the only way is to reload completely WooCommerce checkout page, to get all refreshed checkout fields.

You can use the following function, that uses JavaScript/jQuery, to catch Ajax coupon events on the checkout page. Each time, a customer try to apply a coupon or either remove it, the page will be reloaded. You can adjust the 2 timeouts in the function, if needed.

The code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'autoreload_checkout_on_coupon_event' );
function autoreload_checkout_on_coupon_event() {
    // Set the correct timeout value (in milliseconds)
    $timout1 = 600; // when applying a coupon
    $timout2 = 1500; // when removing a coupon
 
    wc_enqueue_js( "$.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(j, s) {
            if(s.url === '/?wc-ajax=apply_coupon' || s.url === '/?wc-ajax=remove_coupon') {
                var time = s.url === '/?wc-ajax=apply_coupon' ? {$timout1} : {$timout2};
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.reload();
                }, time);
            }
        }
    });");
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: Thank you! This works exactly as expected, however I had to increase the timeout to 1500. Before that it worked only when coupon was added, but not removed. With 1500 works in both cases.

Comment: I have updated my code… There are now 2 different times, one when applying a coupon (600 ms) and another when removing a coupon (1500 ms).